# How can I get VS debugger to cough up the derived class goods?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio to compile some code. It uses NVI to defensively assert- something like this:

```
class Base {
    virtual T DoSomething() = 0;
public:
    T DoStuff() {
         auto result = DoSomething();
         assert(check(result));
         return result;
    }
};
```

The problem is that when the assertion fails, the debugger won't show me which derived class is causing the problem, and since DoSomething() has already returned then it's not on top of the call stack anymore. I've also had problems where the debugger won't call virtual functions, claiming they have no address, when they obviously have to have an address in the vtable to be called.

How can I discover the derived class causing the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

A hackish way to obtain that information would be to add tracepoints in all derived classes's `DoSomething` and then simply look at which one was last when the assertion failed.

To add a tracepoint, add a normal breakpoint, right-click the red dot and select "When Hit...". Then set it to print information that includes the current function name (and possibly the current thread, if relevant).

Comment: I've got quite a few derived classes so I'd really rather avoid that if possible.